# tidyr and rlang errors

Tags: r, tidyr

```
library(tidyr)
pl_spread<-spread(pl,my_name,my_val,-col)
```

Got the following error.

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.1.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required
```

How could I resolve the error?

Answer (score 5):

I think the issue is that ‘rlang’ 0.1.1 is already loaded, but >= 0.2.0 is required

Have you tried updating rlang?

Comment: Amazing inference.  Spot on.

Comment: Yes. I did update.packages('rlang'). Nothing happened

Comment: Did it update rlang to 0.2.0? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rlang/index.html did you restart R?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19103502)

Comment: @AndréKool It does though. The problem is the package not being the required version as evidenced by the error message. Would you feel better if I changed the last line to be a command instead of a question?